# Smullyan Logic Puzzle: Either Tiger behind Door 1 or Gold behind Door 2

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, puzzle

"The prisoner is presented with two doors. In a room behind each door is either gold or a tiger. The sign on the doors are either both true or both are false.

Door 1: Either there is a tiger behind this door or gold behind the second door.

Door 2: There is gold behind this door.

Which door should the prisoner open?"

I have been trying to figure out the answer to this question. If I interpret Sign 1 as an inclusive or, then I end up getting 3 "no contradiction" cases, but it doesn't tell me which Door is the best choice (unless we actually care about probability such as 2/3 chance of getting Gold). To mitigate this, the best I could come up with is to interpret Sign 1 as an exclusive or.

[Solution attempt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1GfpJ.jpg)

EDIT: Here are other places on the internet where the same problem appears.

http://pi.math.cornell.edu/~araymer/Puzzle/PuzzleNights.html

(Page 4) http://www2.gcc.edu/dept/math/faculty/BancroftED/teaching/handouts/MATH213_rules_of_inference.pdf

https://www.ibtimes.co.uk/mathematician-puzzle-maker-raymond-smullyan-dead-97-1605912

Comment: "In a room behind each door is either gold or a tiger." – that sounds as if there are four possibilities, independently either gold or a tiger behind each door. "Which door should the prisoner open?" – that seems to imply that she should open a door. But if she came to the conclusion that there's a tiger behind both doors, she shouldn't open either. So perhaps you meant "Behind one door there is gold and behind the other there is a tiger"?

Comment: @joriki If there is a tiger behind both doors, then statement 1 is true and statement 2 is false, in conflict with the problem statement, so only $3$ possibilities remain.  I feel sure this is what the OP means.

Comment: Even if there are two tigers the person still must open a door.  ... sucks to be her, I guess.

Comment: @fleablood: Well, the puzzle doesn't say that the prisoner must open a door.

Comment: Not as the OP puts it.  But I believe the story is that he must open a door, but I haven't read the book in years. Anyway we are nitpicking.  The idea is we must figure out which door if either is safe.

Answer (score 1):

Smullyan, like all of math, uses the inclusive or as the default.

If door 1 is false, there is gold behind door 1 and a tiger behind 2.  Then 2 is also false, and there is a tiger behind 2.  This is consistent.

If door 1 is true so is 2 and there is gold behind 2.  We do not know what is behind 1 because the gold behind door 2 is enough to make it true.

As stated there is no solution to the problem.  I don't have this book (is it The Lady or the Tiger?) but the ones I have of his are very carefully proofread.  Do you have the problem right?

Comment: The problem came from a class quiz, and I do think the problem statement is copied correctly, because the same problem appears in other places on the internet. The only issue is I could not find an answer to them. Here are the links I found:

http://pi.math.cornell.edu/~araymer/Puzzle/PuzzleNights.html
--
(Page 4) http://www2.gcc.edu/dept/math/faculty/BancroftED/teaching/handouts/MATH213_rules_of_inference.pdf
--
https://www.ibtimes.co.uk/mathematician-puzzle-maker-raymond-smullyan-dead-97-1605912

Comment: I think my logic is sound, so stand by my claim that the puzzle does not have an answer.  The fact that you can't find one seems to support this, though some sites do not publish answers.  If I were in a class, I would just write it up this way.

Answer (score 1):

Did Smullyen *say* there was a solution?

If the "or" is inclusive then, if they are both true there is Gold behind door 2 and we don't know about Door 1; it could have either.  And if they are both false then there is a tiger behind Door 2, and gold behind door 1.

So are we to assume that the likelihood truth or false is 50-50?  What about Gold or tiger given any flexibility?

Id say go with Door 1-- it definitely has gold in one case but doesn't definitely have a tiger in the other... but keep your fingers crossed.

....

If its an exclusive or, which I doubt as Ross Millikan points out why I think that, then

If they are both true then there is gold behind both.

If they both are false then there is gold behind door one and a tiger behind the door two.

......

But just because a problem can be stated, doesn't mean it can be solved.  If it's an inclusive "or" it *can't* be resolved, but who ever said it could?